# Drawing arcs in ArcGIS

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime-net

I need to draw several arcs in an ArcGIS overlay. I want to make a function where with a location, angle and distance, draw an arc like the attached file.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should create a new [PolygonBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PolygonBuilder.html), [add the center point](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MultipartBuilder-1.AddPoint.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_MultipartBuilder_1_AddPoint_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_MapPoint_), then add an [EllipticArcSegment](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.EllipticArcSegment.-ctor.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_EllipticArcSegment__ctor_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_MapPoint_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_SpatialReference_).

You then call [ToGeometry()](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.GeometryBuilder-1.ToGeometry.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryBuilder_1_ToGeometry) on the PolygonBuilder to get the output polygon.

Read the [documentation on the EllipticArcSegment constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.EllipticArcSegment.-ctor.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_EllipticArcSegment__ctor_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_MapPoint_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_System_Double_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_SpatialReference_) to make sure you use the right units for the distances.

Comment: I forget I and using SceneView not MapView. I want to draw it in SceneView . Do you know how?

Comment: I've replied to your follow-up question in Esri Community with some suggestions: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-net-questions/ellipticarcsegment-in-sceneview/m-p/1200218#M11226